# C# TCP Server for simple chat

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm writing my first TCP server using Microsoft's supplied Async examples.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx

I have everything working from the example. I am extending it as a simple chat program. But I am having trouble following the steps of this program (probably because of its async nature). When a message is received, it echoes back to the client and closes the socket. I do not see where it goes back to re-open the socket.

```
public static void StartListening() {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // The DNS name of the computer
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true) {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept( 
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener );

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        try {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Also, is it not normal to leave the socket open?

Comment: Do you know how to write blocking echo server? If you do, then you should read about reactor and proactor pattern.

Comment: The following line : listener.Listen(100).

Comment: This is one of the bad MS samples. The async IO here is not really async because it waits for completion. Pointless.

Comment: @usr that's very misleading of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a message is received, it echoes back to the client and closes the socket. I do not see where it goes back to re-open the socket.

That is because it doesn't. The communication is done, the server receives, sends a reply and is done with that connection. It just continues to wait for new connections on the listening socket. You have a while (true). You'll keep waiting for new incoming connections in the accept call. You'll get a new socket for each new client.

> Also, is it not normal to leave the socket open

Yes, the listening socket remains open. It is kept open to keep on receiving new connections using accept

A better way to write a echo server using async and await can be found here : [Using .Net 4.5 Async Feature for Socket Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630827/using-net-4-5-async-feature-for-socket-programming)

Comment: So the socket is still open, but the connection to that client is closed? I supposed my actual question should have been, `is it normal to leave the connection to the client open`, not the socket.

Comment: You have it all wrong. A listening socket is in listening state and is never used in a real connection. Whenever there is an incoming connection, what will happen is that the listening socket is cloned into a new socket, but this is a servicing socket that belongs to a socket pair containing this servicing socket and the connection socket. The socket pair identifies the connection. A listening socket is never part of a socket pair and hence there is no connection it belongs to. It is only used as a way to establish a connection.

Comment: See also my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054673/tcp-listener-and-client-listening-to-specfic-ip/30060384#30060384. Please mark as usefull or answer if this helps you.

Comment: Okay, your linked post does help a lot. So I'll try one more time! Is it normal to leave the service socket open ? :)

Comment: The servicing socket is closed in your sample code : handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both); handler.Close(); Webservers that have a clear request reply mechanism will close the connection. Same for echoservers, timeofday. But a chat system will typically leave the sockets open for a longer time, depending on their implementation of course.

Comment: That is what I thought. Thank you.